# implementation of readProcess for grep command line?

Tags: haskell

I have a shell command line which i want to use in Haskell ,f.e.:

`grep -n "358" cameraTest.owl`

I have already tried that on ghci :

```
readProcess "grep" ["-n","358"] "cameraTest.owl"
```

but it doesn't work.

How could i do with the function `readProcess` in Haskell ?

**Getting error**

```
Prelude System.Process> readProcess "grep" ["-n","358"] "cameraTest.owl"
*** Exception: readProcess: grep "-n" "358" (exit 1): failed
```

Comment: In what way does this currently not work?  Do you not get any response back?  Does it throw an error?  What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v%3areadProcess), the third parameter of `readProcess` is a string representing the standard input. But in your case, you seem to be grepping a file, so no standard input is needed. Just pass the file name as another of the arguments inside the list.

Like this:

```
readProcess "grep" ["-n","358","cameraTest.owl"] ""
```

But there's another problem with invoking `grep`, though. `grep` in Linux returns a [non-zero exit code](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) when no lines are found. But `readProcess` interprets any non-zero exit code as an error and throws an exception, which may not be the behaviour you want.

So one solution is to rely on the lower-level `createProcess` function, that doesn't throw an exception when the exit code is non-zero. But in that case you'll have to write code that reads the process' `stdout` by yourself.

**Edit:** as Tim mentions in his comment, you can also use `readProcessWithExitCode`. I forgot about that function.

Comment: I'm getting an error which is : No instance for (Show (String -> IO String))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (String -> IO String))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: Do i must put the code on a do statement ? How could i extract the String from my IO String ? How could i solve that situation ?

Comment: @Damiii Be sure to enter the final `""` as well, I forgot to put it in the first version of my answer.

Comment: I see ! Thanks it worked ! :) Just one question, readProcess returns an IO String, right ? if i wanted to manipulated as a String , how could i do that ?

Comment: @Damiii In Haskell, anything that is the result of an I/O operation is tagged with `IO`. You can't extract the pure value that is wrapped in an `IO`. But `IO` is an instance of `Functor`, so you can use something `fmap` to apply a funtion to the value inside the IO. `IO` is also a `Monad`, so you can use `>>=` to perform IO actions that depend on the results of previous IO actions. The so-called "do-notation" is syntactic sugar for chains of `>>=`. Here is a tutorial http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_IO

Comment: Isn't there any other process which could give me an String as an output beside of IO String ?

Comment: `readProcessWithExitCode` is like `readProcess` except it returns the error code instead of raising an exception on non-zero.  (Or just `catch` the exception.)

Comment: @Damiii I meant the ExitCode type, that corresponds to the exit code of the spawned external process.